# Read a SQL query, email individuals their records listed in table, and keep record/time stamp of last report sent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a novice python programmer trying to create an ongoing reporting, and I have no clue where to start. I tired searching and didn't find a lot that is close to what I am trying to create. Any bit of help/gudidence is appreciated

**What I am trying to create:**

1. Read a SQL Query (in data we have records with each of owner for
   cancelled jobs)
2. Email the owner of the project
3. Keep a timestamp or a running record (something similar) on what has
   been sent or not so we don't resend records that has already been
   sent to the owner.
4. Automate (I am thinking I can do this via windows task scheduler)

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to `alter` the SQL tables?

Comment: @LV98 as far as editing the table. No. I am joining couple of tables to get the data.

Comment: Create a duplicate table - with an extra column of Boolean type 1 for true and 0 for false? And update it if other table updates.

Comment: @LV98 that's a great idea, there is not a lot of records, I wonder if i can just create a excel export and keep a running record there?

Comment: I prefer to keep data where it belongs. Instead of all over the place. You'll be making your job complex and annoying.

Comment: @LV98 The only thing is that I have never created a table on the database at my job. didn't have the need to. Not sure if I have the permission, I can check. Can you guide me on Step 1 and 2, if you have any suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Sure - I'll be available now. I'll help you with the Python too